# How to play local video in React component without using any third-party library

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Actually, I need to load the local video in the background screen of a div, I have already gone through several links using Stackoverflow and other resources.

But unable to find a solution other than the  tag of HTML5, but I need a different solution than this.

Comment: what's wrong in using html iframe / video tags ?

Comment: @jayavel there is nothing wrong with <Video> tag, I need an alternative solution